# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers produces no output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've followed the [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/web-api/advanced/analyzers.md) to enable web API analyzers in my .NET 6 web API project. I see `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers` listed under the Dependencies/Analyzers tree in Solution Explorer. The properties of the individual inspections show the error level set to Warning. I have controllers annotated with `[ApiController]` and no return types documented. But the analyzer produces no output. The undocumented returns are not marked with squiggles, and the project rebuilds with no warnings. I have restarted VS. Analyzers in general are working; my own code generator produces output.

Is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers` working at all in the latest VS2022? I found an [improperly closed issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26341) from 2020 that may point to the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The analyzer does not recognize returns in ternary expressions.**

This seems to be a bug in the analyzer. Most of my controller actions return like this:

```
return result != null ? Ok(result) : NotFound();
```

If I change that to an `if` statement, the analyzer highlights `NotFound()` and emits a warning as expected.

It still doesn't warn that I haven't documented what `Ok()` returns. I'm not sure if it's supposed to.